# float left is not working as it should

Tags: html, css

I have these html tags

```
<div class="items-row cols-3 row-0">
  <div class="item column-1"></div>
  <div class="item column-2"></div>
  <div class="item column-3"></div>
</div>
<div class="items-row cols-3 row-1">
  <div class="item column-1"></div>
  <div class="item column-2"></div>
  <div class="item column-3"></div>
</div>
<div class="items-row cols-3 row-2">
  <div class="item column-1"></div>
  <div class="item column-2"></div>
  <div class="item column-3"></div>
</div>
```

And I wanted to float left as this

```
.items-row{float: left;} /*tried !important also*/
```

[test site](http://nepotech.com/ss/smartsolution/products.html)

but this is not floating to left as it should. If this is width problem here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8KFvp/) of which main div width is smaller anyway but floating to left.

Comment: your divs are not closed? why is that?

Comment: here in question </div> was missed

Comment: is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/VfLtc/1/

Comment: Yeah! in the fiddle it works but did you see in test site? there it doesn't work.

Comment: Just try what I wrote in the fiddle and see if it works

Comment: Width is too large and consider adding a clearfix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i am assuming you are doing wrong i debug it and found

replace this css with your css and this will work

```
.item {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 5px 10px;
}
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sarfarazdesigner/8KFvp/1/)

**Updated**

Replace this css to your css and it will works

```
.items-row {
    width: 33.33%;
    float: left;
}
.item {
    margin:0 !important;  
}
.column-1, .column-2, .column-3 {
    /*width: 55%; remove width  */
}
```

one more important thing please remove all `.column-` selectors you are selecting them multiple times so make sure css applied it on only one time

Comment: Yeah! I could do by setting .item to float: left but it doesn't display as what I want.

Comment: In your demo one two three is displaying horizontally but I need one two three to be displayed vertically.

Comment: @C-Link for this you have to float parent div

Comment: @C-Link don't give width to the parent element in your fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/8KFvp/2/

Comment: @Mr_Green I was assuming just it is because of width so I'm trying to mention about width only.

Comment: @TheMechanic yes, exactly I wanted to float to parent div but not working. you can check that test site.

Comment: @C-Link Give `float: left` to `.item` class in your website.

Comment: @C-Link i got your issue and found the problem for this you have to do so many changes in your css

Comment: Should I remove that with jquery. the column-1, column-2, ... coz a huge website

Comment: nope you don't need to remove it only remove it from css and target only once

Comment: i removed all in css but it is still giving styles of that class. so I must remove it with jquery. and plus 1 for effort of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should close your `<div>` tags!

See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VfLtc/1).

**HTML:**

```
<div class="items-row cols-3 row-0">
    <div class="item column-1">1</div>
    <div class="item column-2">2</div>
    <div class="item column-3">3</div>
</div>
<div class="items-row cols-3 row-1">
    <div class="item column-1">1</div>
    <div class="item column-2">2</div>
    <div class="item column-3">3</div>
</div>
<div class="items-row cols-3 row-2">
  <div class="item column-1">1</div>
  <div class="item column-2">2</div>
  <div class="item column-3">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: In the fiddle it does but in my site it didn't. see test site

Comment: please post the code of your website it will become much more easier for me to give a solution and indeed for others!

Comment: P.S the demo site you added when you remove the widths it works just fine! then what's the matter? see this http://jsfiddle.net/8KFvp/3/

Comment: @C-Link when I add the content of those divs into another div just like your website, it acts fine! see this: http://jsfiddle.net/VfLtc/2/

Comment: What are you doing man? Perhaps you didn't understand my problem see @The mechanic answer. that's fine.

Comment: OK! It's you will, you may accept your answer, I just want to help the community!

Comment: What are you doing man? mean to say your last commented fiddle is containing wrong htmls. and that's all please don't take negative.

Answer (score 0):

please try below code

```
<div class="items-row cols-3 row-0">
   <div class="item column-1"></div>
   <div class="item column-2"></div>
   <div class="item column-3"></div>
</div>
<div class="items-row cols-3 row-1">
   <div class="item column-1"></div>
   <div class="item column-2"></div>
   <div class="item column-3"></div>
</div>
<div class="items-row cols-3 row-2">
   <div class="item column-1"></div>
   <div class="item column-2"></div>
   <div class="item column-3"></div>
</div>
```

please replace below css. I have set div width because of float property apply with width.

```
 .items-row{float:left; width:200px;}
```